# Combining 4 queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following queries:

Query 1:

```
    SELECT so.ClientID, 'All Channels' as CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product,
Sum(so.Amount) Amount, Sum(so.Value_CP) Value_CP
into #t1
FROM RG_SalesOut_Report so
WHERE so.Block=0 AND so.[All Sources]='SalesOUT'AND so.Value_CP>0 AND so.Amount>0 AND
so.Brand in('Brand 1', 'Brand 2')
GROUP BY so.ClientID, so.CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product
```

Query 2:

```
select t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product,
Sum(t1.Amount) AS Amount, Sum(t1.Value_CP) AS Value_CP
into #t2
from #t1 t1
group by t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product
```

Query 3:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t2.ClientID desc) as ID, *, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product) AS Code
into #t3
from #t2 t2
group by t2.ClientID, t2.CustomerGroup, t2.StatementID, t2.Brand, t2.Product, t2.Amount, t2.Value_CP, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product)
ORDER BY t2.ClientID DESC, t2.Product, t2.StatementID desc
```

Query 4:

```
select tab1.ClientID, tab1.CustomerGroup, convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,tab1.StatementID,104)),104) AS StatementID, tab1.Brand,
tab1.Product, tab1.Amount, tab1.Value_CP, IIF(tab1.code=tab2.code, DATEDIFF(MONTH,tab2.StatementID, tab1.StatementID), 0) AS M_SALES
FROM #t3 tab1
RIGHT JOIN #t3 tab2
ON tab1.ID=tab2.ID-1
where tab1.StatementID >= '01.01.2013'
order by tab1.ID asc
```

how to combine 4 queries into one?
I'm using SQL Server 2012, I've to use `order by` in the #T3, because I getting wrong data in calculated field (M_Sales)

as you can see, the results of the previous query is used in the following query, please consider this
thanks

Comment: You need to use UNION ALL after Each Query ended (not last one).... Order by you need to give in last query only with alias field name, it will automatically same order for all 4 queries

Comment: i can't use `UNOIN ALL`, `union all` is combining the results of each query, the results of the previous query is used in the following query

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice the same. With Cursor it may be solve but taking 4 cursors might give performance issue.

Comment: I can run 4 times, all queries are processed in 4 minutes, if it possible to combine them without changing any conditions?

Comment: Please provide the table design for the columns of `RG_Sales_Output_Report`; only the columns needed for the queries are required.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [Common table expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of temp tables:

```
WITH T1 AS
(   SELECT so.ClientID, 'All Channels' as CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product,
    Sum(so.Amount) Amount, Sum(so.Value_CP) Value_CP
    FROM RG_SalesOut_Report so
    WHERE so.Block=0 AND so.[All Sources]='SalesOUT'AND so.Value_CP>0 AND so.Amount>0 AND
    so.Brand in('Brand 1', 'Brand 2')
    GROUP BY so.ClientID, so.CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product
), T2 AS
(   select t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product,
    Sum(t1.Amount) AS Amount, Sum(t1.Value_CP) AS Value_CP
    from t1
    group by t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product
), T3 AS
(   select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t2.ClientID desc) as ID, *, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product) AS Code
    from t2
    group by t2.ClientID, t2.CustomerGroup, t2.StatementID, t2.Brand, t2.Product, t2.Amount, t2.Value_CP, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product)
)
select tab1.ClientID, tab1.CustomerGroup, convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,tab1.StatementID,104)),104) AS StatementID, tab1.Brand,
tab1.Product, tab1.Amount, tab1.Value_CP, IIF(tab1.code=tab2.code, DATEDIFF(MONTH,tab2.StatementID, tab1.StatementID), 0) AS M_SALES
FROM t3 tab1
RIGHT JOIN t3 tab2
ON tab1.ID=tab2.ID-1
where tab1.StatementID >= '01.01.2013'
order by tab1.ID asc;
```

Your final select is flawed though, your outer table is `tab1`, but your where clause `where tab1.StatementID >= '01.01.2013'` ensures that no rows in `tab1` can have a null StatementID, essentially turning your right join into an inner join.

I am fairly certain that you can simplify your entire query to this though:

```
WITH T1 AS
(   SELECT  so.ClientID, 
            CustomerGroup = 'All Channels', 
            so.StatementID, 
            so.Brand, 
            so.Product,
            Code = CONCAT(so.ClientID, so.Product),
            Amount = SUM(so.Amount), 
            Value_CP = SUM(so.Value_CP)
    FROM    RG_SalesOut_Report so
    WHERE   so.Block = 0 
    AND     so.[All Sources] = 'SalesOUT'
    AND     so.Value_CP > 0 
    AND     so.Amount > 0 
    AND     so.Brand IN ('Brand 1', 'Brand 2')
    GROUP BY so.ClientID, so.CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product
)
SELECT  ClientID, 
        CustomerGroup, 
        StatementID,
        Brand,
        Product, 
        Amount, 
        Value_CP, 
        M_SALES = IIF(Code = LEAD(code) OVER(ORDER BY ClientID DESC),
                        DATEDIFF(MONTH,LEAD(StatementID) OVER(ORDER BY ClientID), tab1.StatementID), 
                        0)
FROM    t1
WHERE   StatementID >= '01.01.2013'
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: The following clauses cannot be used in the CTE_query_definition:
-ORDER BY (except when a TOP clause is specified)
-INTO
-OPTION clause with query hints
-FOR BROWSE

Comment: if we delete order by then we getting wrong results in calculated field (M_Sales)

Comment: I've removed the offending order by, this should not affect the result of M_Sales.

Comment: i've received the following mistakes: **Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "t2.ClientID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "t2.Product" could not be bound.**

Comment: Sorry, I've received the following mistakes: **Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 't2'.**

Comment: i've received the wrong results of M_Sales, we've to add order by after Query 1

Comment: The order of query 1 is completely irrelevant - your join is based on the product of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, and the `ORDER BY` within that.

Answer (score 0):

If you see, your query 1 and query 2 will be giving same output as they are doing grouping on same fields.
Then again you want to do a group by on lesser fields from them.

For this kind of situations, group by cube is best option.

It will give you aggregation on each possible combination of fields in group by expression and you can use that according to your requirement.

Check this URL [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for further information.

Comment: no in query 1 and query 2 i'm giving different output: Query 1: 5,791 million rows, Query 2: 5,775 million rows

Comment: ok. That is due to incorrect query. You don't need to group by so.customergroup in that as you are giving a fixed string for customer group, while your table might contain multiple customergroups. So remove so.customergroup from group by clause in first query.